# Gradient color for css triangle

Tags: css, navigation, breadcrumbs, linear-gradients

I have navigation menu which has css arrow. I could get the gradient effect to the navigation menu items but not able to get it for arrow.

```
<ul id="content_navigation">
        <li><a href="">Test Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Test Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Test Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Test Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="current">Test Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS is quite long so added working fiddle below.

Here is the working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qBcjq/17/)

Found a **[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431596/css-gradient-for-triangle-shaped-arrow)** with perfect answer but I am not able to implement the same in my code.

Comment: You cannot achieve this with the border-color triangels. However what you can do is use the pseudoelement rotated by 45° with diagonal gradients. You need to adjust the z-index accordingly.

Comment: @Christoph well it is possible to give. Check my updated question, there is a similar question link

Comment: @Sowmya this is exactly what i told you. Rotate the pseudo element and apply the gradient to it. I'll post you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The key points for achieving this are a rotation + skew and the rotated gradient:

```
#content_navigation a::after,
#content_navigation a::before{
   -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) skew(20deg,20deg);
   -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg,  #fefefe 0%,#e1e1e1 100%);
   /* just for better understanding you should change the bg-color
   to understand how this is done*/
   background:red;
   border-top:1px solid red;
   border-right:1px solid red;
}
```

The big disadvantage is that you need to declare an explicit width + height on those elements. Also the pseudoelement might overlap content. To avoid this you need to modify the z-index to push it to the background. The advantage over the border-trick is you could even use a `box-shadow`.

Here is a link of your [modified Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qBcjq/19/) working in Chrome only. But you should be able to work this out on your own now.