# Gradient CSS arrow

Tags: html, css, geometry, css-shapes

How is it possible to make a CSS arrow as a gradient instead os a solid colour?

Here is my CSS"

```
.breadcrumbDivider .arrow-right {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid gold; 
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 360px;
}
```

I tried using the CSS gradient background image gradient but it takes the border parameter but unsure how to overcome this?

Here is the gradient I am trying to use...

```
  background-color: #c9bc9e;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#c9bc9e), to(#a89464));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9bc9e, #a89464);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9bc9e, #a89464);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c9bc9e, #a89464);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c9bc9e, #a89464);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #c9bc9e,#a89464);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#c9bc9e', endColorStr='#a89464');
```

Comment: Way simpler solution is to use a rectangle rotated by 90°. Great implementation by Roland Shultz here http://sassmeister.com/gist/c8708658a5f83dfa4fea and a link to the original thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431596/css-gradient-for-triangle-shaped-arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made this by 'cutting out' the arrow from a square div, instead of 'generating' an arrow. It even has a hover effect:

```css
.arrow {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: rgb(169, 3, 41);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1)), color-stop(44%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#6d0019', GradientType=0);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  border-top: 40px solid white;
  border-bottom: 40px solid white;
  z-index: 10;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid white;
  border-bottom: 100px solid white;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  z-index: 10;
}
.perc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(30, 87, 153);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 50%, rgba(32, 124, 202, 1) 51%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(32, 124, 202, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 50%, rgba(32, 124, 202, 1) 51%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 50%, rgba(32, 124, 202, 1) 51%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 50%, rgba(32, 124, 202, 1) 51%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 50%, rgba(32, 124, 202, 1) 51%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8', GradientType=0);
  z-index: 5;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.arrow:hover .perc {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <div class="perc"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Note**

- Originally designed for a progress bar, but hover effect can be removed if necessary.
- Is suitable for a **block coloured background only**

---

So, if I cut the 'fancy stuff' and show you how it works:

Hover the one below to see the magic:

```css
.arrow {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: rgb(169, 3, 41);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1)), color-stop(44%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 44%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#6d0019', GradientType=0);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  border-top: 40px solid white;
  border-bottom: 40px solid white;
  z-index: 10;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  border-top: 100px solid white;
  border-bottom: 100px solid white;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  z-index: 10;
}
.arrow:hover:before {
  border-top: 40px solid tomato;
  border-bottom: 40px solid tomato;
}
.arrow:hover:after {
  border-top: 100px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: 100px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: Thats a wonderful solution, how do I make it so the arrow is inline with the box, so it is just the point and the height is the same height as the arrow body if that makes sense?

Comment: @coder123: check updated 'last snippet'